# does Github support OAuth 20 resource owner password credential grant type?

Tags: github, oauth, access-token

Does Github support OAuth 20 resource owner password credential grant type? I know you can use basic authentication for CLI to login with Github account. The basic authentication can be used to directly request all sorts of user data (like emails, teams, etc). I am curiously to know if CL can request an OAuth access_token by using ROPC, then uses access_token (similar to authorization code grant type) to request user data.

Answer (score 1):

Github's oAuth implementation only supports [authorization code grant type](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/). As an alternative (and similar to CLI), you can [retrieve a personal access token via basic auth](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/), then use the token for subsequent resource access.

Comment: OK. So CLI can not request access_token and introspect access_token. CLI has to use basic auth (substitute password with PAT) directly to request user data.